# How to intercept system-wide "copy to clipboard" event in Android

Tags: android, clipboard

I have a service running in background. Is there a way for it to intercept global clipboard events?

In particular, I'd like to be notified when the user copies something into the clipboard.

Comment: With `android.content.ClipboardManager`, using the `OnPrimaryClipChangedListener` interface and the `addPrimaryClipChangedListener()` method.

Comment: Great! Copy and paste that in a post and I'll mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The necessary classes can be found in `android.content.ClipboardManager`. Use the `OnPrimaryClipChangedListener` interface to create a listener, and the `addPrimaryClipChangedListener()` method to set it as a listener.

Please note that it is `android.content.ClipboardManager`, and not `android.text.ClipboardManager`, which is the old text-only version which was deprecated in API Level 11.

[`android.content.ClipboardManager` docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ClipboardManager.html)